# Не отображаются колонки из запроса

Tags: sql-server

Прикладываю скриншот запроса и сразу под ним - результат его исполнения:

[image: Запрос + результат]

Собственно, в чём вопрос: почему в результате исполнения я не вижу колонки PARENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL, CHILD_HIERARCHY_LEVEL ?

Comment: потому что выбираете из `acsc.*` а не просто `*` ? добавьте `z.*` к выборке

Comment: у вас 2 запроса на скриншоте, из вопроса не понятно какой из 2 вы запускаете + текст запроса лучше привести в текстовом виде, чтобы отвечающие смогли внести в него правки, а не перепечатывать ваш скриншот, пока не переделаете - не уберу минус

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в `SELECT` у вас `ACSC.*`, а нужные вам поля из таблицы `ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY`, добавьте после `SELECT ACSC.*`, `z.PARENT_HIERARCHY_LEVEL, z.CHILD_HIERARCHY_LEVEL`

Comment: там есть алиас `z`

Comment: @teran точно, сейчас поправлю ответ, спасибо